# can another .htaccess file can work in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter site http://piyukarts.in/mss/ where in .htaccess file under mss contains

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

but i cant access a link `http://piyukarts.in/mss/posts`, but i can access `piyukarts.in/mss/index.php/posts`, with this `index.php/` `after mss/`

`piyukarts.in/` is wordpress site, also having a .htaccess file

Please help.. thanks a ton in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I made this change in `.htaccess` file and its working fine now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mss  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mss/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> can another .htaccess file can work in subfolder

is:

**Yes.**
.htaccess files in any folder in the file path tree to the file, will be applied to the file.

so file as `/root/home/site/includes/css/horses.css` the htaccess in any of those folders would be applied to the file `horses.css` .